# How to prevent NSColorWell from changing selected text color

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstextview, nscolorwell

I have several `NSColorWell`s for different purposes, and I also have some `NSTextView`s. Whenever some text is selected in one of the text views, if I change the selected color of any of the color wells, selected text's color also changes. I don't want that. How do I prevent color wells from changing selected text in another control?

Comment: Maybe deselect your text once the color well is opened?

Comment: `NSColorPanel` is sending `changeColor:` to the first responder. If you don't want to change the color of the text at all, override `-[NSTextView changeColor:]` and do nothing.

Comment: @Willeke it apparently also sends `setColor:` too and if I override that too, then I can't set the color when I really want too

Comment: `NSTextView` doesn't have a method `setColor:` (OS X 10.10).

Comment: @Willeke I meant `setTextColor:`

Comment: `setTextColor:` isn't called in my test app. How do you change the color of the color well?

Comment: @Willeke sorry, Xcode was misguiding me by showing `setTextColor:` like an inherited method from NSColorWell (just checked, it wasn't). I can change it by `setColor:` but obviously, I'd need to do perform some extra logic like if I actually set the color by myself, or if it was automatically sent by Cocoa after me selecting a text view, but the sender is the same and I can't distinguish if it was me really changing a color of if it's automatically raised. in my case, I was trying to make two discrete color wells for arbitrary number of text boxes, but apparently I'll need to start from scratch

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Willeke I'm trying to have two color wells, one for text's foreground color, one for background color. user can add an arbitrary number of text views. the wells will be set to the the currently selected text boxes foreground and background. but whenever I select a color well or text view, they sync the foreground/selected color in well, without a chance for me to intercept.

Comment: I had the same problem years ago but I can't remember how I fixed it and can't find the project. I'm searching.

Comment: @Willeke currently, I've ended up making those color wells' methods overriden not to take color from what's selected, but I can't sync the colors from the wells to the text views in realtime. I'm just using its color property for newly created text boxes. not ideal, but does the job in my app for now.

Comment: Found it. The color doesn't change if `usesFontPanel` is false. I knew it was something illogical.

Comment: @Willeke I'll be trying it ASAP, thanks! you may post it as an answer though :)

Comment: @Can Poyrazoğlu Have you made, at the end, "two color wells, one for text's foreground color, one for background color" ? I am trying to do the same and can't find solution.

Comment: @VYT to be honest I still couldn't get time for it.